# Discovering virtualized URL for http app deployed in YARN with spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, hadoop-yarn, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I successfully deployed a stream in to YARN  created using SCDF which looks something like --
 `stream create --name httpTest--definition "http --server.port=9001|....`

I was able to scale the http source apps with clustermodify to multiple instances. Does SCDF writes a virtualized / static / proxy URL somewhere in the YARN Registry ([see here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/registry/using-the-yarn-service-registry.html)) so that upstream applications can bind to? How another application outside Yarn can post to above http server with port 9001 that too scaled horizontally?

If i deploy a spring boot web application in docker-swarm and scale it, docker swarm manages to distribute the load among all applications. How does it happen in case of YARN & SCDF in particualr?

When I invoke following in dataflow shell -- it fails too..

```
http post --target http://localhost:9001 --data empty
```

Error Message :

```
Failed to access http endpoint http://localhost:9001
```

All other variations of replacing localhost with hostname/ipaddress are failing too?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.

Alternative Design -- Use Kafka destination instead of HTTP Source since HTTP source's URL isn't guaranteed to be unique once deployed in yarn containers ( -- which can be published to a consuming application. )
Alternatively, we will need to patch the OOTB HTTP Source app to enlist itself (at boot time)  with Spring's Eureka server implementation and use a gateway as a smart proxy.